# unable to commit <filename>.java files through svn

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

hi I am facing a strange issue.
I am unable to commit my java files into svn repository.
If I rename the .java file to .txt file it is commiting later I can svn-rename the file to .java.Other file extensions like html, css, js , jar etc are getting committed.when I try to commit, I get the following error

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: File  
Error:  'D:\repos\poc\Java\qa\commpany\poc\requestsBase.java'  
Error:  is out of date  
Error: '/svn/svn/!svn/txr/324-av/poc/Java/qa/mannai/poc/requestsBase.java'  
Error:  path not found  
Error: You have to update your working copy first.  
Completed!:
```

things I tried:
I tried update, update to head revision, fully recursive update.
I tried a different checkout, issue persists.
I tried adding an empty file named .java. but still it is not commiting.
i tried deleting the .svn folder and taking the update.

no luck so far. any help appreciated.
I have many files in different package structure. renaming is not an option.

(visual svn server Version: 3.5.3)(subversion 1.9.4) 
 tortoise svn client version(TortoiseSVN 1.7.15, Build 25753 - 64 Bit -dev) (Subversion 1.7.18)

Note: can someone suggest if these versions are compatible.
I cannot upgrade the svn client, its version depends on a software suite use.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had the same issue and it had nothing to do with SVN at all.

I was using the SVN Server behind a IIS reverse proxy, which in turn had request filtering of any *.java files. After I removed this rule, I was able to commit any *.java file.

So maybe there is something like this configured on your server too? Cause that is pretty much the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete your working copy and the do the svn update. Ofc do a backup of the file before. Then you can manually insert afterwards.

I have had the same issue before.